Was bedeutet "doch schon mal"?
Könntet ihr mir bitte sagen, was doch schon mal im Kontext unten bedeutet?

Person A: Ihnen ist aber bewusst,  dass dort hauptsächlich Männer
arbeiten und es möglich ist, dass Sie die einzige Frau auf der
gesamten Baustelle sind.
Person B: Ja, das ist mir bewusst. Damit kann ich sehr gut umgehen.
Person A: In Ordnung. Das klingt doch schon mal gut.

Ich habe die Aussage in diesem Video am 2 Minuten und 28 Secunden.

Es hat keine wirklich inhaltliche Bedeutung. A drückt damit aus, dass er denkt, dass das größte Problem damit ausgeräumt sein dürfte.


Das klingt doch schon mal gut.

Das sind Modalpartikel. Das eine ist doch, das andere schon mal als Kombination der Modalpartikel schon und mal. Modalpartikel haben für sich selbst keine Bedeutung. Ihre Bedeutung muss aus dem Zusammenhang erschlossen werden. Lass uns die vier Varianten vergleichen:

Das klingt gut.
Das klingt doch gut. — Das klingt gut, im Gegensatz zu den Zweifeln, die du vorgebracht hast.
Das klingt schon mal gut — Das klingt gut, auf den ersten Blick jedenfalls.
Das klingt doch schon mal gut — Das klingt gut, mach dir keine Sorgen.

Das doch wischt also die Zweifel des Gegenübers vom Tisch, während das schon mal erklärt, dass der Sprecher fürs erste auch keine Zweifel hat. Zusammen bedeutet es, dass alle Zweifel fürs erste beiseite gelegt werden können, kurz: Mach dir keine Sorgen.
